# Change the origin of a 3D mesh vtk

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, vtk

I'm working with 3D meshes using vtk. I want to apply the scale transformation filter but it works holding, as a reference, the origin of the mesh. Now I would like to apply the same transformation but using a different fixed point.
The idea is to change the origin of the mesh to that point and than to apply the filter. Is it possible in vtk or with other libraries? Is there another method that works better?

I attach here two images that explain the problem.

Thank you in advance!

[image: In the first the mesh has the center as origin; in the second the origin is a surface's point]

Comment: By vtk mesh you mean vtkPolyData? Or you're using a vtkSphereSource? The idea is to compute the center of the sphere, translate the sphere of (- center) so it's centered to the origin, scale it and finally re-translate it of (+center). It would be easier to help you if you posted some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve